# using a static method in a different class

Tags: java, package

Let us suppose we have a class:

```
package package1;

public class Car {
    public static int brake()
    {
         int x;
         //some functionalities
    }
    //other functionalities
}
```

I want to ask for using this method brake in classes of different package, do we need to include package name also? -- `int xyz=package1.Car.brake();` or simply `Car.brake();` will work

Comment: Give it a try and your IDE will complain if it's not accessible. If you are calling the method from another class within the same package or if you have imported the class correctly (`import package1.Car;`) then using `Car.brake();` is sufficient, otherwise, yes you will need to include the relevant package/path to the class.

Comment: @sorifiend yeah my question is regarding different package only. My servlet and class containing the static method are in different packages. Even though servlet accesses the static method without giving its package name. So why is it happening I wanted to know.

Comment: Because of the `import` statement.

Comment: actually this is not specific to `static` - to *address* a class in a different package you must use the fully qualified name (e.g. `package1.Car`); **or** have the *namespace* imported (e.g. `import package1.*` or `import package1.Car`) and use the simple name (e.g. `Car`) - no matter if the class is being used to access one of its members, create a new instance, use it in instanceof, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import package or use full path of method:

***First solution:***

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        package1.Car.brake();
    }

}
```

***Second solution:***

```
import package1.Car;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car.brake();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add import statement like `import package1.Car;` and then you can use `Car.brake();` to call the function. Read more about imports [here](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/packages-import)

Comment: thanks "import package1.Car;" caused it to work

Comment: can you please tell in static method can we have simple int statements or we need to have static int ? like int x or static int x?

Comment: @krr You can not declare variable as `static` inside a method.

Comment: you can't use the `static` keyword inside a method. You need to use int x. Read more about the static keyword from https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java